# GA4 and Firebase don't show revenue

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have a Firebase account with a project including two apps: android and ios. Recently, I integrated the Firebase project with a Google Analytics 4 account so that I could track in-app events.

I've also configured the Firebase SDK according to the documentation in: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce (my app is e-commerce).

Thera are manny events like:

- add_to_cart
- purchase

In my Firebase and Analytics account, I'm able to see how many times users have triggered the events, but I'm not able to see the revenue from purchase:

[google analytics print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaZNE.png)

Although I see the monetary value as a parameter, it does not appear as revenue.

My currency is set as "BRL" and the price parameter is a number.

Answer (score 1):

We figured out the problem:

Our code did not include the parameter "value". Although we were collecting "price", without the "value" parameter, Google doesn't recognize revenue.

Exemple code from google:

```
    gtag('event', 'purchase', {
  affiliation: 'Google Store',
  coupon: 'SUMMER_FUN',
  currency: 'USD',
  items: [{
    item_id: 'SKU_12345',
    item_name: 'jeggings',
    coupon: 'SUMMER_FUN',
    discount: 2.22,
    affiliation: 'Google Store',
    item_brand: 'Gucci',
    item_category: 'pants',
    item_variant: 'black',
    price: 9.99,
    currency: 'USD',
    quantity: 1
  }, {
    item_id: 'SKU_12346',
    item_name: 'jeggings',
    coupon: 'SUMMER_FUN',
    discount: 2.22,
    affiliation: 'Google Store',
    item_brand: 'Gucci',
    item_category: 'pants',
    item_variant: 'gray',
    price: 9.99,
    currency: 'USD',
    quantity: 1
  }],
  transaction_id: 'T_12345',
  shipping: 3.33,
  value: 21.09,
  tax: 2.22
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I had the same problem and forgot to add value parameter to GA4.